# Using PowerBI to visualize large amounts of data on a SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, powerbi, azure-synapse

I have a SQL DW which is about 30 GB. I want to use PowerBI to visualize this data, but I noticed PowerBI desktop [only supports file size up to 250MB](http://blogs.technet.com/b/powerbisupport/archive/2015/04/26/power-bi-workbook-size-limitations.aspx). What is the best way to connect to PowerBI to visualize this data?

Comment: My apologies if my question is naive: What do you mean by *visualize*? Is there a particular query(s) you want to run against your dataset?

Comment: I edited the question. I was trying to ask what is the best way to connect and use PowerBI with a SQL DW data set larger than the 250MB supported by PowerBI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of choices depending on your use case:

1. Direct query of the source data
2. View based aggregations of the source data

**Direct Query**

For smaller datasets (think in the thousands of rows), you can simply [connect PowerBI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-integrate-power-bi/) directly to Azure SQL Data Warehouse and use the table view to pull in the data as necessary.

**View Based Aggregations**

For larger datasets (think millions, billions, even trillions of rows) you're better served by running the aggregations within SQL Data Warehouse. This can take the shape of view that is creating the aggregations (think sales by hour instead of every individual sale) or you can create a permanent table at data loading time through a [CTAS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas/) operation that contains the aggregations your users commonly query against. This latter CTAS operation model is a simple select with filter operation for the user (say Aggregated Sales greater than today - 90 days). Once the view or reporting table is created, you can simply connect to PowerBI as you normally would.

The PowerBI team has a blog post - [Exploring Azure SQL Data Warehouse with PowerBI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2015/06/24/exploring-azure-sql-data-warehouse-with-power-bi.aspx) - that covers this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a query (power query - M) that retrieves only the required data level (ie groups, joins, filters, etc). If done right the queries are translated to tsql and only limited amount of data is downloaded into power bi designer